How to remove default padding around a Gauge?
The Gauge struct looks like this
Gauge(value: 100, in: 0...100) { }
    .gaugeStyle(.accessoryLinearCapacity)
    .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: -90))
    .frame(width: 20)
    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
    .tint(Gradient(colors: [.green, .green, .orange, .red]))


I would like use the height shown in this picture.
I have tried to find a way with environment(), but without any luck.
My 2 gauges are shown in code.

try to add .padding(.horizontal, -8).
it's your width (20) / 2 and minus green line width (2)

I have tried both things, but i wiil try it again, may copy Soundflix solution, and start from there.

Does this answer your question? How to draw a vertical linear Gauge in SwiftUI nicely?

i got it working now, thanks to
i'm not sure

.frame(maxHeight: .infinity),

is the right way to go.

Gauge(value: rf12, in: 0...127) {
}
.frame(width: 60, height: 7)
.rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: -90))
.frame(width: 10)
.frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
.tint(Gradient(colors: [.red, .green, .green]))

